# Signing User - Designer Agreement

Tags: web-development, wordpress, design

I will convert an HTML design to Wordpress Theme for my customer. And we have to make an agreement via email . Which articles should i write to agreement ? Are there any draft for this ? Which agreements, you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

The AIGA Standard Form of Agreement for Design Services is quite popular.

Check it out @ aiga.org

I also found this Contract Template very useful:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/how-to-spot-a-sketchy-client-plus-a-contract-template/